# Accessing parent's/object's properties in prototype

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var App = function () {
     this.interfaces = [];
};

App.prototype.user = {
    create: function (name) {
        this.interfaces.push(name);
    }
};

var app = new App;

app.user.create('John Doe');
```

It'll unleash the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

That's because `this`, in `user.create` has a different context than `App`'s one. Okay, but how can I access the property `interfaces` from `App` in `user.create`?

---

Demonstration: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se4s53ed/)

Comment: Some previous questions: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20javascript%20get%20parent%20object

Comment: Oh, thank you! It's hard to think to search for `Using 'this' within nested Prototype sub-objects`. =P

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately you'll find that the answer is that you can't. The method only knows of the object on which it was invoked. This is worked out dynamically at call time.